# How to list a directory in a remote host?

Tags: php, directory

There is a way to list a directory in a remote host without ftp ?
A way using php will be better.

thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the remote host or does it generate the directory listing by itself (by Apache's mod_autoindex, for example)?

Comment: `read access` what kind of method/protocol is used to read?

Comment: With read-only access this is not possible. You can use your imagination brainstorming the kinds of security vulnerabilities this would present if it *were possible.*

Comment: @Cheery It's a basic Apache server of a website with a read access to specifics subdirectories.

Comment: @damson so, get this listing, for example with simple `file_get_contents` and parse it for the listed files with regexp or DOMDocument methods.

Comment: Will they let you put a php file on their side?

Comment: @seanbreeden cause the server is in read-only mode for public.

Comment: @Cheery I was thought a the same way but the regexp is fat

Comment: @damson Why is it 'fat'? The structure of the typical directory listing generated by Apache is very simple.

Comment: @Cheery Yes, I agree. It was the lazy maybe. I going to try this way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, unless you get some sort of shell access to the remote host, or the remote host provides you with an API to list it (remote API can be an API, or a FILE SERVER FILE SYSTEM access such as NFS or SAMBA).